Internal Server Error (500) with Next.js and react-bootstrap Integration
Next.js version 14.2.4 Node version: 20.10.0
When I create a next app with "npx create-next-app@latest" and npm run dev immediately after creating it, I am getting the following error.
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Could not find the module "C:\Users\Pradeep Joshi\Desktop\next js\next-landing\node_modules\react-bootstrap\esm\Navbar.js#default#Brand" in the React Client Manifest. This is probably a bug in the React Server Components bundler.

Call Stack
Next.js
<unknown>
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:267034)
eN
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:267229)
eF
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:272113)
<unknown>
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:265943)
Array.toJSON
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:266407)
eq
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:274775)
ej
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:264920)
e_
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:263962)
e
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:268224)
eF
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:268712)
<unknown>
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:265943)
Array.toJSON
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:266407)
eq
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:274775)
eJ
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:275293)
Timeout._onTimeout
file:///C:/Users/Pradeep%20Joshi/Desktop/next%20js/next-landing/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:265080)

I have tired to emptied the Node.js package manager cache using npm cache clean --force and reinstalled dependencies with npm install.Restarted the Next.js development server (npm run dev) to refresh and rebuild the application.
Despite these efforts, the problem persists, indicating that there might be a deeper or more specific issue related to the bundling or configuration of Next.js and react-bootstrap in your project setup.

I had the same problem and found the solution on this link https://medium.com/@fdikmen/fixing-could-not-find-the-module-error-in-nextjs-with-ant-design-3ae2cfe0160d
Hope this helps!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
